# No enabled views in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I need to import cost data from non Google marketing campaign, so I'm trying to add a new Data Import (type Cost Data) in Google Analytics

[image]

but in the next step I have not any views to select.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programing related may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Please check if you have full EDIT access to do this action.

Comment: How to transfer my question to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming problem. It is a problem with an online service.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the Edit-level permission for the view you want to use, and that you have views set up in Google Analytics.